# How do I disable the sleep button on my keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, power-management

I have a "power button" on my keyboard that enables standby or hibernate. I can't find the mapping of this key anywhere in "sytem settings>Keyboard", "system>power management", "compiz config> or similar (where I could find it before unity). How can I disable (not remap) this button?

I do not want to disable hibernate/sleep altogether, it's simply this key that gets pressed a lot by accident and it's getting quite annoying.

Comment: Try a chisel and a pair of pliers.

Comment: I was asking about this on the forum and annoyingly still have no answer. The GUI setting disappeared with the move to GTK3.

Comment: Remove the key from keyboard with a pencil. (Don't do that, just a joke until final answer arrises...=) But I made it in some strange work situations... Just put the key back in when you done! Don't break keyboards!

Comment: I just disassembled the keyboard and removed the button. Problem solved.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Disable the suspend button in your system

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend "nothing"
```

Revert to the default value

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend "suspend"
```

---

Disable the sleep button in your system

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep "nothing"
```

Revert to the default value

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep "hibernate"
```

---

Disable the hibernate button in your system

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate "nothing"
```

Revert to the default value

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate "hibernate"
```

---

Settings those options above does not disable the functions in your system, you can still use the cog wheel menu to hibernate / suspend, this only disables keyboard and other buttons you might have in your computer.

Comment: I filed a bug against ubuntu gnome-control-center keyboard shortcuts GUI.  It should manage these buttons like other keyboard buttons: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1079190

Comment: Didn't work for me on 18.04. I set all 3 to "interactive", but pushing the "sleep" button on the keyboard just locks me out immediately.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `reset` for reverting stuff?

Comment: I'm looking into this on ubuntu 18.  It looks like it would be handled by systemd-logind, except that gsd-media-keys from gnome-settings-daemon is taking over control.

Comment: Can confirm, sleep button still pushes me out of my PC.

Comment: Did not work on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 38):

Dconf Editor is the recommend replacment to gconf editor for Unity. You can get dconf in the software center or by typing `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` in the terminal.

With Dconf editor, navigate to `org` `gnome` `settings-daemon` `plugins` `power`. There you can change what the sleep button does, as well as many other buttons on your keyboard.

[image]

Comment: +1, essentially the GUI version of the accepted answer :), thanks

Comment: +1, IMO since this is a Gnome question the GUI ought to be the default vector.

Comment: that's so cool .

Comment: These settings are getting ignored in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 12):

Since Ubuntu 18.04, [Bruno Pereira's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/115423/834652) doesn't seem to work anymore.

To disable any key, you will need to [get its code](https://askubuntu.com/a/245363/834652):

```
xmodmap -pk | grep -i sleep
```

For me, the sleep button has the code `150` as you can see:

```
    150     0x1008ff2f (XF86Sleep)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff2f (XF86Sleep)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0x1008ff2f (XF86Sleep)  0x1008ff2f (XF86Sleep)
```

Once you have the key code, you mainly have two ways to automatically disable it.

### Disable for some users

If you just need to disable it for one or many users, you can add this command to the [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html), assuming the key code of your sleep button is `150`:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 150='
```

If the user logs off, the button will be enabled again. If you want to keep it disabled, try the other method instead.

### Disable for every users

The button will be disabled after each booting. You will need the administrator privileges for this. Edit this file:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
```

The line we will have to edit looks like `<SOMETHING> = <your_keycode>`. Once you found it, add `//` at the beginning to comment it. In my case, I had to change this:

```
    <I150> = 150;   // #define KEY_SLEEP               142
```

Into this:

```
//  <I150> = 150;   // #define KEY_SLEEP               142
```

---

**Note:** With both methods, the button will still be enabled for few seconds when booting or logging in.

**Sources:**

- [How to disable a keyboard key in Linux (Ubuntu)?](https://superuser.com/questions/775785/how-to-disable-a-keyboard-key-in-linux-ubuntu)
- [How can I persistently remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-can-i-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thank you. To apply this change, Alt+F2, type the single letter r then Enter, it will restart gnome GUI without killing any app. **Drawback**: you can't use the key anymore, like in a shortcut, direct or with a modifier.

Answer (score 5):

Have you also tried this one?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend "nothing"
```

I did all 3 from the linked-to question and it fixed this for me (x86 on 12.04).

*EDIT:* Here's a single command that does all 3:

```
for x in button-{suspend,sleep,hibernate}; do 
  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power $x "nothing";
done
```

Comment: Thank You very much - it has solved my problem of unwanted suspends (the key is on my keyboard direct next to calculator key) ===> I use now gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend "interactive"

Comment: ... but if I remember correct: I had try in previous set button-suspend too (just forget it list in Q) but id does not help too. But now (maybe some update?) does :-) and thanks your reply i have try it again and IT WORKS! End good all good :-)

Comment: ooh, "interactive" sounds potentially useful -- though I think I'll stick with "nothing" for now.  I looked up this question because I was sitting on the floor with my tvputer and my 14-month-old daughter seemed to enjoy pushing the silver Moon button on the corner of my keyboard.  And all the other buttons, which made retyping my password a bit of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me, I don't have Gnome I use OpenBox, as most of you will know is very "bare bones" with a Ubuntu 18.04 kernel running.

This solution should work for most systems.

1. Go to this path: `/etc/systemd`
2. Edit as root: `logind.config`
3. ADD or uncomment these lines;

   ```
   HandlePowerKey=ignore
   HandleSuspendKey=ignore
   HandleHibernateKey=ignore
   ```

Why did I do this, this cheap goofy keyboard has "Power", "Sleep", "Wake Up" following the F1-F12 keys, when I go to press F12 I hit power and the system powers off and my work is lost!

Comment: Related answer [about How to disable suspend on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128676/349837) (with systemd)