# How do I disable the sleep button on my keyboard in U12.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, power-management

Hello I have read Q and A : [How do I disable the sleep button on my keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115333/how-do-i-disable-the-sleep-button-on-my-keyboard/115423#115423)

but in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit has

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep "nothing"`

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate "nothing"`

NO EFFECT.

After pressing sleep button on keyboard, PC goes immediately to sleep (STR suspend to ram).
Log out->in doesn't help.

Any Ideas ?