# Getting character key code mappings in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, xorg, xserver

I am trying to play around with some keyboard layouts in Ubuntu. Now there is a program called **showkey** which lets me see the keycode for any key pressed in the terminal.
Is there any command to get the corresponding character for a specific keycode. For example when I type in

```
sudo showkey
//I get the response in the form
keycode num press/release
```

I was just wondering if I have the keycode, can I get the character mapping back so that I know which character I actually pressed?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Run `xev` from a terminal. This will give you a new window.

Place your mouse pointer in this window, type some keys and watch for results in the terminal.

Comment: `xev -even keyboard` for keyboard only events

Comment: @Minner do you mean `xev -event keyboard`?

Answer (score 16):

In order to get a terminal print-out of all key codes and corresponding keys, run the following command in a terminal:

```
xmodmap -pk
```

It's not easy to view in a (small) terminal window, so if you want to save the output to a file, just add the command to let the terminal output be saved in a file (in your current working directory in the terminal):

```
xmodmap -pk > mykeyboard.txt
```

Full description of how to use xmodmap [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xmodmap.1.html).