# "sleep" button on keyboard puts computer into hibernate

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, hibernate, lock-screen

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04.

I changed my shortcut for "Lock screen" to the sleep button on my keyboard.

But instead of just locking the screen it puts my computer into hibernation/suspend mode, which is kind of annoying. I can't find where the hibernation mode is bound to the sleep button.

I already tried `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'nothing'` ([as mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115333/how-do-i-disable-the-sleep-button-on-my-keyboard)) but it doesn't affect the sleep button and it still goes into hibernation/suspend.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable suspend button (`button-suspend`):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'nothing'
```

But then the sleep/suspend button did nothing at all, even with the system shortcut, so I had to utilize the CompizConfig Settings Manager: `Commands > Enable commands`.

I added following for command line 0: `gnome-screensaver-command -l`. Then I switched to the tab "Key Bindings" and grabbed my key for command 0. (It is set to `XF86Sleep` now).

Everything works as expected now.

Comment: Everything worked for me in 14.04 except I can't get regular `XF86Sleep` to bind (even after changing the config setting to 'nothing'). However I was able to bind `Alt`+`XF86Sleep`. Also, I wanted it to lock the screen _and_ turn off the monitor, so I used `gnome-screensaver-command -l; xset dpms force off`.