# How to disable sleep/hibernation key (or entirely) on Kubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, hibernate

I have a keyboard for my desktop computer with a Sleep/Hibernate key on it: .  Pressing this key causes my desktop to hibernate, but it can't wake-up from this state correctly (loss of all USB input). I want to disable the sleep key.

I'm unable to find any button in the settings that control the behaviour of this button. The power management only offers control for the system power button.

It appears to be desktop specific as "[How do I disable the sleep button on my keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115333/how-do-i-disable-the-sleep-button-on-my-keyboard)" refers to the Unity/Gnome settings, but I can't find anything for Kubuntu/KDE.

I'm okay with disabling hibernate entirely if I can't control the key. I don't need hibernation on my desktop.

*Kubuntu 16.04*

Answer (score 4):

I have recently faced the same issue with keyboard. It has 'Power' and 'Sleep' buttons near `F12` key, which I use to toggle `yakuake`.

I have disabled these buttons via KDE system settings (in Kubuntu 18.04) in `Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts > Power Management`. Then just changed `Global` shortcut for 'Power Off', 'Suspend' and 'Hibernate' actions.

I think, the settings path can slightly differ in other version of KDE, or Kubuntu.

[image: Example path to find these settings]