# Disable sleep key (not button) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, shortcut-keys

The answers given in [How do I disable the sleep button on my keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115333/how-do-i-disable-the-sleep-button-on-my-keyboard) do not work in Ubuntu 18.04.  On my keyboard, <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> puts my system to sleep, and I accidentally hit that key combo often.

Here's the output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cpuid                  16384  0
btrfs                1122304  0
zstd_compress         163840  1 btrfs
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
ufs                    77824  0
qnx4                   16384  0
hfsplus               106496  0
hfs                    57344  0
minix                  32768  0
ntfs                  102400  0
msdos                  20480  0
jfs                   188416  0
xfs                  1200128  0
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
nfsv3                  40960  1
rpcsec_gss_krb5        36864  0
nfsv4                 577536  0
nfs                   262144  3 nfsv4,nfsv3
fscache                61440  2 nfsv4,nfs
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
video                  45056  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  12
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm                98304  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mei_me                 40960  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd                    81920  34 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
ioatdma                57344  0
dca                    16384  1 ioatdma
mac_hid                16384  0
wmi                    24576  4 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,mxm_wmi
binfmt_misc            20480  1
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
nfsd                  339968  13
auth_rpcgss            61440  2 nfsd,rpcsec_gss_krb5
nfs_acl                16384  2 nfsd,nfsv3
lockd                  90112  3 nfsd,nfs,nfsv3
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
parport_pc             36864  0
sunrpc                335872  28 auth_rpcgss,nfsd,rpcsec_gss_krb5,nfsv4,nfs_acl,lockd,nfs,nfsv3
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
nvidia_drm             40960  16
nvidia_modeset       1110016  8 nvidia_drm
nvidia              14340096  582 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 nvidia_drm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  19 nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler        53248  2 nvidia,ipmi_devintf
e1000e                249856  0
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
ahci                   36864  1
libahci                32768  1 ahci
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsmod`? Thanks.