# How to disable sleep / suspend / hibernate HP keyboard buttons for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, power-management

Already tried all solutions from: [How do I disable the sleep button on my keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115333/how-do-i-disable-the-sleep-button-on-my-keyboard)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend "nothing"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep "nothing"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate "nothing"
```

and I have now with **dconf-tools**:

[image]

In my case **HP Hewlett Packard WZ972AA ABA Classic Keyboard**:

[image]

This "Moon" button still working.. Any another ideas?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the Gnome Power settings you can set the `systemd` settings found in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

My laptop looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf

#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#UserTasksMax=12288
```

Notice on my system the only option I've changed is `HandleLidswitch`. For your system I would override these defaults:

```
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
```

to this:

```
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
```

`systemd` is a little unique in that a line beginning with a hashtag (`#`) is not only a comment but also represents the default action taken.

Unfortunately I don't have your keyboard to test this configuration.

**NOTE:** After saving changes either reboot to activate or use:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

Comment: this method doesn't works

Comment: @Crantisz I added `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` to answer. Do you have the same keyboard as shown in question? What make and model of computer do you have?

Comment: This worked for me on 18.04

Comment: Doesn't work for a Lenovo P52 (sleep button in top right corner) under Ubuntu 20.04. The `systemctl restart ...` gave me a black screen so I had to reboot anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Not a solution, but a workaround, as it disables suspend.
Follow these two steps:

1. Add  `HandleSuspendKey=ignore` to the `[Login]` section of `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.
   If you have enabled debug level in `logind` logs you get log entries like:

   ```
   ... systemd-logind[518]: Refusing operation, as it is turned off.
   ```

   in the journal but it still suspends on some other trigger.
2. Add `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` with:

   ```
   [Sleep]
   SuspendMode=false
   ```

   Now it still reacts on suspend key presses, but fails with:

   ```
   ...systemd-logind[518]: Failed to process message type=method_call  
   sender=:1.54 destination=:1.1 path=/org/freedesktop/login1  
   interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager member=Suspend cookie=26  
   reply_cookie=0 signature=b error-name=n/a error-message=n/a:  
   Sleep verb not supported in journal
   ```

As said: It's a dirty workaround until someone can find a better solution.

Comment: @zx485 Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1131652/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: I reviewed your edit and admit that my edit was not the best. It was incomplete. I also read the _editing help_ page - again.

Comment: @zx485 **0:-)** We live and we learn...  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

Please try 'xev' to find out if the event (press button) is read by Linux. Maybe the button is direct triggering a function on the mainboard?

On the other hand, if you've got the keycode in `xev`, you should be able to remap the sleep button with something other. See: [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)

Comment: Here the log: KeymapNotify event, serial 112, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ability to configure this was removed from recent versions of gnome-settings-daemon in Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 20.

A quick and dirty solution is to `killall gsd-media-keys` which will prevent all media keys from being handled by gnome, likely including the lid switch.  You'll likely have to have edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to make sure logind handles the keys how you like, and restarted the logind service or your system.

To re-enable the ability to configure this, some small changes are needed to `plugins/gsd-media-keys-manager.c` inside the `gnome-settings-daemon` source.  These changes are in a merge request at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/537 .  Here is how to rebuild gnome-settings-daemon with configuration enabled.  You'll have to enable source repositories in your package management system.

```
$ mkdir ~/local-debs
$ cd ~/local-debs

# install build dependencies
$ sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-settings-daemon

# extract distribution package source
$ sudo apt-get source gnome-settings-daemon

# download the changes
$ wget https://siasky.net/CABb_suQRoRKqFo9zJ9YvGIqlLcpila1OFjUtI-f7uS5xQ/suspend-button-settings

# apply the changes.  `true` as an editor skips editing by making it always successful.
$ cd gnome-settings-daemon-*/
$ patch -p1 < ../suspend-button-settings
$ EDITOR=true dpkg-source --commit . suspend-button-settings ../suspend-button-settings

# build the package, skipping tests and signing
$ DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc

# install the package
$ sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb

# reboot the system, relogin, or terminate and relaunch the `gsd-media-keys` process ...
# ... [do preferred choice] ...

# finally, disable the suspend button
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power suspend-button-action "nothing"

# you can also set it to "interactive" instead of "nothing" to display a power popup
```

Comment: I don't think this feature has made it into the gnome-settings-daemon that ships with 22.04 either.

Comment: In the merge request link, somebody has suggested an existing configuration key, which may make the patch unnecessary; I'm not sure, as I haven't tried it.

Comment: It looks like they suggest `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend-static "[]"`. I just ran that, and it ran, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient since I already applied my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Under X11, I was able to make the suspend key not suspend, without turning off all the media keys or needing to recompile bits of Gnome.

1. Set `HandleSuspendKey=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, and `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind`. **Note that this kills your user session.** I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary.
2. Following [these instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/tuxedocomputers/comments/q7zlbl/disable_suspend_sleep_key/hglzlbw/), identify the keycode for the sleep key with `xmodmap -pk | grep Sleep`. I got `150`. Then run `xmodmap -e 'keycode 150='` to unmap that key, and put that command somewhere, like maybe `~/.xinitrc`, where it can run at login.

This basic approach is unfortunately reported to be hard to make work under Wayland.