# "calc" key always opens gnome-calculator

Tags: shortcut-keys, 23.10, gnome-calculator

I am running Ubuntu 23.10 and even after disabling the shortcut in settings it still launches gnome-calculator.  I want to launch Qalculate without creating symbolic links.  I can set a custom shortcut and it still won't launch, even after removing gnome-calculator.

It's not optimal but [How to change the shortcut for "calculator"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341969/how-to-change-the-shortcut-for-calculator) worked.  Top Answer

Answer (score 0):

In v23.10 I set a new Launcher for Qalculate without any issue.

I took the following steps (after installing the app):

- `Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts` <kbd>></kbd>
- select `Launchers` then `Launch Calculator`
- Set Shortcut > (in my case) <kbd>F12</kbd>
- then select *Set*
- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> et voila!

To note: GNOME Calculator was not installed on my 23.10 instance by default.